# GetHashCode and Equals implementation in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dictionary, gethashcode, equals-operator

I came to this site searching for object comparison in Dictionary, and i came to know that overriding GetHashCode and Equals are a must for doing object comparison in C#.
Here is a piece of code that i have been trying to solve out, using FOREACH iteration Method. But my Boss says to do the same without using any iteration(maybe by using containskey or containsvalue method), due to performance issues. Any help is highly welcome..

```
  public class employee
    {
        public string empname { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public double kinid { get; set; }
        public double managerKin { get; set; }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class manager
    {
        public string managername { get; set; }
        public double kinid { get; set; }

        public override int GetHashCode() 
        { 
          return 17 * managername.GetHashCode() + kinid.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    public class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            employee emp = new employee();
            employee emp2 = new employee();
            manager mng = new manager();
            manager mng2 = new manager();

            emp.empname = "Deepak";
            emp.location = "Pune";
            emp.kinid = 36885;
            emp.managerKin = 007;


            emp2.empname = "Astha";
            emp2.location = "Pune";
            emp2.kinid = 30000;
            emp2.managerKin = 007;

            mng.kinid = 007;
            mng.managername = "Gaurav";
            mng2.kinid = 001;
            mng2.managername = "Surya";

            Dictionary<employee, manager> relations = new Dictionary<employee, manager>();
            relations.Add(emp, mng);
            relations.Add(emp2, mng2);

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("The Manager details are :");
            foreach (var element in relations)
            Console.WriteLine(" \n KINID : {0} \n  Manager'sName :                    {1}",element.Value.kinid, element.Value.managername);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the details of the manager..");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.Write("\nManager's Kin : ");
            double mkin = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Manager's Name : ");
            string mname = Console.ReadLine();

            manager mng1 = new manager();
            mng1.kinid = mkin;
            mng1.managername = mname;
            int hashvalue = 17 * mname.GetHashCode() + mkin.GetHashCode();



            #region BY USING FOREACH LOOP
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var element in relations)
            {
                if (element.Value.GetHashCode() == hashvalue)
                {
                    i += 1;
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The Following employees report to the Manager : {0}", mname);

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(element.Key.empname + " " + element.Key.kinid + " " + element.Key.location + " " + element.Key.managerKin);

                }
            }
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("sorry the manager's details you entered \"{0}\" \"{1}\" does not exist in our database..", mng1.managername, mng1.kinid);

            }
            #endregion

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: -1, Your sample is very long and contains too many unrelated details. Also it is not clear what is your question - as you've already stated dictionary is good for searches by key, so just do it...

Comment: alexei levenkov : you can run this sample code on your debugger.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This question is about searching by value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For searching an object in a dictionary using the ContainsKey or ContainsValue keyword, compiler uses two implicit functions i.e. GetHashCode() and Equals(). So when we have an object for comparison, we need to Override both these methods !!

Here is the code

```
#region USING DICTIONARY TO STORE CLASS OBJECTS (check employee existence and print manager's name)
public class employee
{
    public string empname { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public double kinid { get; set; }
    public double managerKin { get; set; }

    //public override bool Equals(object obj) // ANY OF THE TWO EQUALS METHOD WORKS.
    //{
    //    employee otheremployee;
    //    otheremployee = (employee)obj;
    //    return (otheremployee.kinid == this.kinid && otheremployee.location == this.location && otheremployee.empname == this.empname && otheremployee.managerKin == this.managerKin);

    //}
    public override bool Equals(object obj)   //When Running this entire code, put a break-point on both the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods, and see the execution flow.
    {
        employee otheremployee;
        otheremployee = (employee)obj;
        return (obj.GetHashCode() == otheremployee.GetHashCode());

    }
    public override int GetHashCode()    //When Running this entire code, put a break-point on both the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods, and see the execution flow.
    {
        //int temp = base.GetHashCode(); // DONT USE THIS
        //return base.GetHashCode();
        int temp = empname.GetHashCode() + location.GetHashCode() + kinid.GetHashCode() + managerKin.GetHashCode();
        return temp;
    }
}

public class manager
{
    public string managername { get; set; }
    public double kinid { get; set; }


   
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
public class program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        employee emp = new employee();
        employee emp2 = new employee();
        manager mng = new manager();
        manager mng2 = new manager();

        emp.empname = "Deepak";
        emp.location = "Pune";
        emp.kinid = 36885;
        emp.managerKin = 007;


        emp2.empname = "Astha";
        emp2.location = "Pune";
        emp2.kinid = 30000;
        emp2.managerKin = 001;

        mng.kinid = 007;
        mng.managername = "Gaurav";
        mng2.kinid = 001;
        mng2.managername = "Surya";

        Dictionary<employee, manager> relations = new Dictionary<employee, manager>();
        relations.Add(emp, mng); // put a BreakPoint here and see the execution flow
        relations.Add(emp2, mng2);// put a BreakPoint here and see the execution flow

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("The Employee details are :");
        foreach (var element in relations)
            Console.WriteLine(" \n Employee Name : {0} \n Location : {1} \n Employee KinId : {2} \n Manager's KinId : {3} ",
                element.Key.empname, element.Key.location, element.Key.kinid, element.Key.managerKin);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the details of the Employee..");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write("\nEmployee Name : "); string ename = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Location : "); string elocn = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Employee KinId : "); double ekinid = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Manager's ID : "); double emngr = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        employee emp1 = new employee();
        emp1.empname = ename;
        emp1.location = elocn;
        emp1.kinid = ekinid;
        emp1.managerKin = emngr;


        int i = 0; // This variable acts as a indicator to find whether the Employee Key exists or not.
        if (relations.ContainsKey(emp1)) //Put a break point here and see the execution flow.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the Employee : {0} exists..", emp1.empname);
            Console.WriteLine("the Employee reports to the following manager : {0} \n and the Manager's KinId is {1}.", (relations[emp1]).managername, relations[emp1].kinid);
            i = 1;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (i == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the details of the employee named {0} does not exist !!", emp1.empname);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

#endregion
```

Comment: Two employees with different empname, different location... can have the same GetHashCode. It is called collision. When You say they are Equal, it is completely wrong. It would not happen often so the program would seem to work, but there is a bug waiting.

Comment: Combining more that one hash returned by GetHashCode() is best done with an XOR operation to better permute the results. Additionally circular shifting left or right after each result from xor can yield in a better permutation.
int temp = empname.GetHashCode() + location.GetHashCode() + kinid.GetHashCode() + managerKin.GetHashCode();

Replace With:
 int temp = empname.GetHashCode() ^ location.GetHashCode() ^ kinid.GetHashCode() ^ managerKin.GetHashCode();

Answer (score 1):

To search element in dictionary you can use ContainsKey, ContainsValue methods or just write LINQ query

```
var dict = (from pair in relations
where pair.Value.Equals(mng1)
select pair).ToDictionary<employee,manager>();
```

Comment: This can lead to an exception. It is possible (and likely) for multiple employees to have the same manager and ToDictionary hates duplicate keys. GroupBy and then ToDictionary would work. Oh, hmm, I missed it ... thought you were creating a reverse mapping. Seems silly to put it back as a dictionary.

Comment: You're right in case there was Dictionary<manager, employee>, but here's opposite case.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary.ContainsKey(employee)` won't help here because the employee is the "unknown" value, and `Contains` won't help because it takes a `KeyValuePair<employee,manager>` and ... once again ... no employee is known. `ContainsValue(manager)` won't help because it doesn't return any key *and* because it's not a key, it is an `O(n)` operation, not an `O(1)` like `ContainsKey`!

With the *current* structure the only way is with some form of looping, although I would write it like this:

```
// Key is Employee, Value is Manager
// This is O(n)
var theEmployees = relations
  .Where(rel => rel.Value.Equals(theManager))
  .Select(rel => rel.Key);
```

This will only work after `manager` is given a valid `Equals` implementation. Note that the hash code *is not used at all*. (**Because objects that are *different* may share the *same* hash-code, just comparing the hash-code is not a replacement for `Equals`, or `==`, or `CompareTo`!** -- depending on which one is appropriate.)

If there will be *many* such queries then the initial structure can be "inverted".

```
// Build a reverse lookup-up
var employeesForManager = relations
  .GroupBy(rel => rel.Value)            // group on Manager
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g);    // Key is the group's Manager

// This is O(1), but only valid AFTER employeesForManager is [re-]generated
var theEmployees = employeesForManager[theManager]
```

This will only work if `manager` has a valid `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementation. (GetHashCode is required because `manager` objects are used the key to the new Dictionary.)

As for which is "better" -- well, that depends. It is silly to create the reverse-lookup to only use it once, for instance. There is no performance problem until there is a performance problem: write clean code and profile.

Happy coding.

Comment: Infact I did correct the problem. And i made use of containskey properly. All you need to do is to override gethashcode method and equals method in your key class. I will shortly post the corrected code. Happy Coding.

Comment: @LetsKickSomeAssin.net Yay :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to compare 2 instances for equality, you should override the Equals method and, it is also good practice to implement `IEquatable<T>`.
When you override Equals, you should also override GetHashcode (this is used when you put your instances in a dictionary to calculate the bucket).

You should not use `GetHashcode` yourselves in order to compare 2 instances of your object for equality; instead you should use `Equals` (or an `EqualityComparer`, which will use the Equals method as well).

If you've implemented GetHashCode and Equals well, then you're able to determine whether a dictionary contains a specific instance by doing:

```
var myDictionary<int, Manager> = new Dictionary<int,Manager>();

myDictionary.ContainsKey (someKey)
```

or

```
var mySet = new HashSet<Manager>();
mySet.Contains(someManagerObject);
```

Comment: This is a new idea, will try this out too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a bug in your final response.

The line

return (obj.GetHashCode() == otheremployee.GetHashCode());

Probably should be

return (this.GetHashCode() == otheremployee.GetHashCode());

That way you are comparing the hash code for this object and the other object.  As it is written in your response you appear to be comparing the other object to itself.